# Specific Equations in Latex

Tags: equations

How could I get that equation?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
      Z = \begin{cases}
          1 & \text{if the outcome is a success} \\
          0 & \text{if the outcome is a failure}
 \end{cases}
 \end{equation}
 \begin{equation}
      Z = \begin{cases*}
          1 & if the outcome is a success \\
          0 & if the outcome is a failure
 \end{cases*}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

While `cases` is suppled by `amsmath` (which is loaded by `mathtools`) `cases*` is provided by the latter. In this the second column is in text mode, hence no need of using `text` macro. `mathtools` provides some other `cases` like environments too. Here is a screen shot from the manual (section 3.4.3, page 18):

[image]

Comment: @Günal: The best way to express gratitude on StackExchange sites is to upvote frequently and to mark good answers as accepted.